# OroCRM - Symfony Class Not finding PHP executable binary after upgrade PHP version from 7.1 to 7.2

Tags: php-7.2, orocrm

After upgrade PHP version 7.1 to 7.2 my OroCRM getting error,

Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: The file “The PHP executable could not be found.” does not exist in /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Component/PhpUtils/Tools/CommandExecutor/AbstractCommandExecutor.php:99 Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/EntityExtendBundle/OroEntityExtendBundle.php(184): Oro\Component\PhpUtils\Tools\CommandExecutor\AbstractCommandExecutor::getPhpExecutable() #1 /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/EntityExtendBundle/OroEntityExtendBundle.php(200): Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\OroEntityExtendBundle->getPhpExecutable() #2 /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/EntityExtendBundle/OroEntityExtendBundle.php(120): Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\OroEntityExtendBundle->getProcess(‘oro:entity-exte…’) #3 /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/EntityExtendBundle/OroEntityExtendBundle.php(101): Oro\Bundle\Enti in /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Component/PhpUtils/Tools/CommandExecutor/AbstractCommandExecutor.php on line 99

How to solve above error?

Comment: Hi Zus, What version of OroCRM do you use?

Comment: Version : 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The error says that Symfony can't find the PHP executable to run some required commands during the request.

Here is the implementation of the method that looks for the PHP executable, that you can check for more details:
https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/4.2/PhpExecutableFinder.php#L38-L84

Usually, to fix that, you should add a PHP package to your PATH environment variable. In your case, it's PHP 7.2 executable. How to do that depends on the OS or the hosting provider you are using.

For example, to configure it on Windows you can follow [the manual on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath)

Comment: My crm versions : * 4.0.0

and updated with following code :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.0/src/Symfony/Component/Process/PhpExecutableFinder.php

Still getting same error.

Comment: Can i get document for adding PHP package to Centos - Nginx environment variable?

Comment: Finally solved, issue is PHP extension not enabled.